# How can i call my node js sever method on vm server from my local machine through ip address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js

I have node.js server that is hosted on vm server in IIS .

I want to call this node server API from my Local machine using asp.net  through local machine IP address and port  but I enable to call this node.js API. I posted below my code :

```
// below this is my node js sever js api method
app.get("/stream", function (request, response) {

});

// below code for call node.js sever api method from local machine
string url = "http://213.*.*.*:Port/stream";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Please provide details about the error message you receive.

Comment: Are you literally using this URL `"http://213.*.*.*:Port/stream"`?

Comment: I am getting this error   "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 213.*.*.*:port"

Comment: Yes jfriend00 this is VM server IP Address and port .

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a full IP address and port number, and not just `213.*.*.*:Port`.

Log into your Vm and find out the IP address. For the port this should be obvious from your code what port you are listening on (typically 3000).